# Insert or update if record is in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a tables Cars and CarDescriptions

> cars: IDCar(int, PK, autoincrement)
>   carsDesciptions(IDDescription,
>   Header(nvarchar),Content(nvarchar),idCar(int,FK)

In application I am adding cars and editing existing ones.

**My problems:**

1.How to save changed Car with descriptions in database ??

I have ID of Car, and I have ID's of Descriptions

Class CarDescirption doesn't have any pool like IsChanged, so

I don't wanna do something like :

1. delete from carsdescriptions where idcar=@idcar
2. insert into cardescriptions (, @Header,@Content,@IDCar)

the record must be updated if is in table, and inserted if doesn't exist in table

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has the best perfomacne:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 7):

In SqlServer 2008 there is [an **UPSERT** command](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) which does exactly this. I didn't try it.

Answer (score 5):

probably something similar with some modification would work

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECt * FORM carsdescriptions WHERE IDCar = @IDCar )
        UPDATE carsdescriptions 
        SET Header = @Header, Content = @Content
        WHERE IDCar = @IDCar
   ELSE
        INSERT INTO carsdescriptions (IDCar, Header, Content)
        VALUES (@IDCar, @Header, @Content)
```

---

Have a look at this article as well, will give you more insight

- [**SQL Server: Best way to Update row if
  exists, Insert if not**](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/30/60273.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a IF EXISTS first to see if the record exists in the table.  If it doesn't, INSERT the new car, else UPDATE the existing record.

Answer (score -1):

First: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Second: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Comment: This is definitively not a very specific answer to the question.

Comment: then delete the this else its noise