# INSERT vs. UPDATE

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following query:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'1',@ip,@idsesiune)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip",ip);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune);

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("User2.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

What i need is to see if there is any record in the table and if there is than update else insert it.How can I achieve that?

Comment: What defines a record as already being in the table? What is the unique data? Essentially you just need to do a SELECT (or a COUNT) query first to find the data and if it is there you can do an UPDATE rather than an INSERT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Exists function in SQL. For Example

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);   
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("if Exists(Select 1 from Raspunsuri where <your unique criteria>)\r\n" +
"Update Raspunsuri set <values you want to set> where <your unique criteria\r\n" +
"else\r\n" +
"INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'1',@ip,@idsesiune)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox1.Text);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip",ip);   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune);
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Sorry, I was away from the PC and didn't see that Curt already posted the same answer as what I suggested.

Comment: It doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 6):

This is probably best done in a Stored Procedure due to the amount of scripting involved (it would be messy inline!).

Pass your parameters to a Stored Procedure and do something like:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT cnp FROM Raspunsuri WHERE cnp=@cnp)
BEGIN
    UPDATE ...
    WHERE cnp=@cnp
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO....
END
```

Assuming `@cnp` is your Primary Key

---

Your SqlCommand would then be changed to:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcedureName", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", textbox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip",ip);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idsesiune", id_sesiune);
```

Comment: I totally agree. Up vote

Comment: -1. As in: My ORM generates Upserts automatically when I tell it to and it doesn ot use a stored procedure. "just do it" ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@@ROWCOUNT` feature from SQL Server.

```
UPDATE Raspunsuri SET (...) WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn='YourValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Raspunsuri VALUES (...)
```

Similar question: [Insert / Update to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362696/insert-or-update-if-record-is-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

> What i need is to see if there is any record in the table and if there is than update else insert 
>   it.How can I achieve that?

Write proper SQL?

Basiacll waht you need to forumlate is known as an "Upsert".

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

hasa good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First you check whether the record is present in the table by writing  a query as "Select count(*) from tablename where columnvalue="something".If count is more than 0 then table has record.So in that case you write an Update statement else write Insert statement. This you can write in your code or by writing a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> What i need is to see if there is any record in the table and if there
>   is than update else insert it.How can I achieve that?

I like @Alex's approach

```
-- For each row in source
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE target
SET <target_columns> = <source_values>
WHERE <target_expression>

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
INSERT target (<target_columns>)
VALUES (<source_values>)

COMMIT
```